Excel VBA to select a folder and load the TXT files inside
Below is part of the code I have that will request user to select a .txt file they want, and it will load to the excel, is it possible to let user select a folder where there is multiple .txt file inside and it will load to the excel? Example, there is a folder named log, inside have log1.txt, log2.txt, etc. User will select folder named log and all the txt files inside will be recorded to the excel sheet I have. Or is there a method whereby I can loop the macro I have based on the number of txt file I have in the folder so it will record each txt file respectively on the excel sheet.
    textFileLocation = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    textDelimiter = ","
    textFileNum = FreeFile
    Open textFileLocation For Input As textFileNum
    textData = Input(LOF(textFileNum), textFileNum)
    Close textFileNum
    tArray() = Split(textData, vbLf)
    For rowNum = LBound(tArray) To UBound(tArray) - 1
        If Len(Trim(tArray(rowNum))) <> 0 Then
            sArray = Split(tArray(rowNum), textDelimiter)
            For colNum = LBound(sArray) To UBound(sArray)
                ActiveSheet.Cells(rowNum + 1, colNum + 1) = sArray(colNum)
            Next colNum
        End If
    Next rowNum

    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(43, 1), Array(70, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers _
    :=True


What do you mean by "so it will record each txt file respectively on the excel sheet"? Would you record each file text bellow the previous one or each file on a new worksheet? If in the same sheet, do the copied text have column headers?  If so, how to proceed? Should the code copy the header only for the first file, or for all of them? Eventually, to know where they starts and ends...

@FaneDuru it will record each file text below the previous one. The current code I have is that user will select a file, and it will paste the data in the text file into a sheet, then it will filter out and copy paste the data I want to another sheet. But right now, I have multiple text file, so I want it to be able to go through all the text file I have in a folder and record it to the excel sheet thank you.

Give us a sample of contents of the text files, so that different solutions can be set up.

@Haluk, I see I didn't include mainly because I scared it will be too long, generally the contents of the text files will be split into 3 columns attribute name (AN), attribute data (AD) and units (U). Afterwards, it will copy and paste the attribute data to another sheet where it will match the attribute name. Example, Device Temp (AN), 280 (AD), kelvin (U). These info in the text file will be recorded into Sheet1, then it will match the (AN) on sheet2 and paste it in. If sheet2 does not have the (AN), it will not record the (AD). This apply to all the text files I have in the folder.

If the text files are the same format each time I'd have the folder path in a cell.  A double-click event to open the folder dialog box and change that.  Then use PowerQuery to import all text files within that folder.

Please, don't expand your question post here in the comments. Instead, edit your question.

How would the PowerQuery work, currently my code works by selecting the log1.txt file and insertting it into Sheet1, then paste the data to Sheet2. Then I will run the code again and select log2.txt file and it will insert it into Sheet1 and paste the data to sheet2. So, what I want is for it to run automatically from log1.txt to log100.txt file and it will do the exact same thing for each log.txt file. The format for each txt file is the same.

I can see in your code textDelimiter = "," What does it mean? Not the columns separator? i can see that you do not use it in TextToColumns...

Please, try the next piece of code. It let you chose the folder to be processed, then iterate between all existing text files, place their content in an array, drop the content in the calculated last row and finally apply TextToColumns. It considers comma as columns separator:
Sub ProcessFilesFromChosenFolder()
  Dim textFileLocation As String, textDelimiter As String, fileName As String, arrTxt
  Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long
  
  Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
  textFileLocation = GetFolderName("This PC") 'if you need it to be open in a specific folder, place here its path
  
  fileName = Dir(textFileLocation & "\*.txt") 'first text file  name
  
  If fileName <> "" Then
    Do While fileName <> ""    'loop since there still are not processed text files
        'place the content of the text file in an array (split by VbCrLf):
        arrTxt = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(textFileLocation & "\" & fileName, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)
        lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'the row where to paste the array content

        'drop the transposed array content:
        ws.Range("A" & IIf(lastR = 1, lastR, lastR + 1)).Resize(UBound(arrTxt) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrTxt)
        
        fileName = Dir 'find the next text file
    Loop
  End If
  'apply TextToColumns to whole returned data:
  ws.Columns(1).TextToColumns Destination:=ws.Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Comma:=True, _
             FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(43, 1), Array(70, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub

Function GetFolderName(InitPath As String) As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

        If InitPath <> "" Then
            If Right$(InitPath, 1) <> "\" Then
                InitPath = InitPath & "\"
            End If
            .InitialFileName = InitPath
        Else
            .InitialFileName = ""   'it starts at This PC...
        End If
        
        If .Show() = True Then
            If .SelectedItems.count > 0 Then
                GetFolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
            End If
        End If

    End With
End Function

Edited:
The next version does not need TextToColumns it splits each initial array row by delimiter (comma) and load a third final array to drop its content after each processed text file:
Sub ProcessFilesFromChosenFolderBis()
  Dim textFileLocation As String, fileName As String, ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long
  Dim arrTxt, arrLine, ColsNo As Long, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long
  Const textDelimiter As String = ","
  
  Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
  textFileLocation = GetFolderName("This PC") 'if you need it to be open in a specific folder, place here its path
  
  fileName = Dir(textFileLocation & "\*.txt") 'first text file  name
  
  If fileName <> "" Then
    Do While fileName <> ""    'loop since there still are not processed text files
        'place the content of the text file in an array (split by VbCrLf):
        arrTxt = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(textFileLocation & "\" & fileName, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)
        ColsNo = UBound(Split(arrTxt(0), textDelimiter)) + 1 ' determine number of columns
        ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arrTxt) + 1, 1 To ColsNo)   'redim the aray to keep the processed data

        For i = 0 To UBound(arrTxt)
            arrLine = Split(arrTxt(i), textDelimiter) 'place each row/line in an array
            For j = 0 To UBound(arrLine): arrFin(i + 1, j + 1) = arrLine(j): Next j 'load final array
        Next i
        
        lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'the row where to paste the array content
        'drop the processed final array content:
        ws.Range("A" & IIf(lastR = 1, lastR, lastR + 1)).Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value = arrFin
        
        fileName = Dir 'find the next text file
    Loop
  End If
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

It uses the same function to determine the folder to be processed.
Second Edit:
The next code needs you to select a text file from the folder you need processing. It does not need the function to browse for folder, anymore:
Sub ProcessFilesFromChosenFolderBis()
  Dim textFileLocation As String, fileName As String, ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long
  Dim arrTxt, arrLine, ColsNo As Long, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long, FullPath
  Const textDelimiter As String = ","
  
  Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
  
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Text Files", "*.txt", 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
             FullPath = .SelectedItems.Item(1) 'selected text file full path
        End If
  End With
  If FullPath = "" Then Exit Sub 'if Cancel pressed, the code stops
  
  textFileLocation = Left(FullPath, InStrRev(FullPath, "\") - 1)
  fileName = Dir(textFileLocation & "\*.txt") 'first text file  name
  
  If fileName <> "" Then
    Do While fileName <> ""    'loop since there still are not processed text files
        'place the content of the text file in an array (split by VbCrLf):
        arrTxt = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(textFileLocation & "\" & fileName, 1).ReadAll, vbCrLf)
        ColsNo = UBound(Split(arrTxt(0), textDelimiter)) + 1 ' determine number of columns
        ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arrTxt) + 1, 1 To ColsNo)   'redim the aray to keep the processed data

        For i = 0 To UBound(arrTxt)
            arrLine = Split(arrTxt(i), textDelimiter) 'place each row/line in an array
            For j = 0 To UBound(arrLine): arrFin(i + 1, j + 1) = arrLine(j): Next j 'load final array
        Next i
        
        lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'the row where to paste the array content
        'drop the processed final array content:
        ws.Range("A" & IIf(lastR = 1, lastR, lastR + 1)).Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value = arrFin: 'Stop
        
        fileName = Dir 'find the next text file
    Loop
  End If
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub


Hi, thanks for the help, it works as what I intended, just a slight issue. When I run the code, it will not show the txt file I have, it will go to my location but I am not able to see it but when I click run it will still go through all my txt file which is why it works but there is some visual issue?

@user23357972 What do you mean by visual issue?  Each text file is open using VBScript which does not have a visual interface. The text file content is placed in a variable almost instant, then it is processed in memory, that's why it is very fast. What do you really need? To make the code stop before each file to be processed and ask for processing confirmation? To write on the fourth column on top of each copied content the file name? I really cannot understand what you want...

I can't really explain in a better term, and I am unable to upload photos so that you would know what I meant, but the code you provided works just fine thanks a lot. But I will just illustrate it a bit more, when it prompts to select the folder, inside the folder it will not show the list of txt file I have. And that's about it not a big issue because if I continue and select ok on the folder, it will still load the txt files inside, so it works perfectly fine.

@user23357972 So, the visual part was related to seeing the files in the folder you choose... If this is a correct understanding I will change the dialog and you will need to select a text file from the respective folder and the code will extract its folder. So, you can see all files in the respective folder. Please confirm that this would be convenient.

Yes, that will be correct thank you

@user23357972 OK. please test the last version (after Second Edit) and send some feedback.

A PowerQuery solution.
In Excel select Data > Get Data > From File > From Folder

In the dialog that opens select the folder containing your text files and then click Transform Data.

Click the two down arrows in the Content column to expand the data.

Click OK on the next screen to import the data.

Apply any further calculations to get the data as you need and press the Close & Load button to import the final table to Excel.
In PQ the Advanced Editor button should give you a script something like below.  You'll also have some helper queries that PQ built for you.
let
    Source = Folder.Files("H:\Test\Text Files"),
    #"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File", each #"Transform File"([Content])),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File"}),
    #"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File"(#"Sample File"))),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table Column1",{{"Source.Name", type text}, {"Attribute Name", type text}, {"Attribute Data", type text}, {"Units", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"

Now we just need to add a function that will allow us to change the file path on the first line of the query.
Create a new blank query using Data > Get Data > From Other Sources > Blank Query.
Add this code to the query - it reads the value from a named range.  I called this query fGetNamedRange.
let GetNamedRange=(NamedRange) => 
    let
        name = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=NamedRange]}[Content],
        value = name{0}[Column1]
    in
        value
in GetNamedRange  

Update the first line of your original query.  I've given the cell a named range of MyFolderPath:
//Source = Folder.Files("H:\Test\Text Files"),
Source = Folder.Files(Text.From(fGetNamedRange("MyFolderPath"))),  


The last step is to add some VBA code that will allow you to update the folder.
In a normal module add this code:
Public Function GetFolderName() As String

    Dim FD As FileDialog
    Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    With FD
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        
        If .Show = -1 Then
            GetFolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    
    Set FD = Nothing

End Function

In the code behind the worksheet where your folder path is kept:
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
        Cancel = True
        Target.Value2 = GetFolderName() & Application.PathSeparator
        
        If MsgBox("Refresh query?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
            ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - Text Files").Refresh 'NB - query is called "Text Files", but must add "Query - " in front of it.
        End If
    End If
End Sub

